# Spagobi Birt report show all data using filter giving errors

Tags: birt, spagobi

I am using SpagoBI BIRT reports. I want to add multiple filters in my report and want to show all data by default. Why do I get errors like:

> Service Error: Cannot evaluate errors on parameter validation